# Install part of APK not All of it

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to test a part of my app as a collection of some and its size 20MB+, and want I mean is to install just some classes to the android phone, not the whole APK

Is that is possible with Android Studio? also, I see installation options in the Run/Debug Configurations that have Deploy option named Custom Artifact but its artifact field is empty, so if that is it how to use it

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try the Instant Run option of Android Studio?

Comment: yes and in some cases I need to install the whole app with the instant run as my changes are more than the re-designing and simple test